# Remove lines with empty values from multidimensional-array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How do you remove the lines that have empty elements from a multidimensional-array in PHP?

For instance, from:

```
1: a, b, c, d
2: d, _, b, a
3: a, b, _, _
4: d, c, b, a
5: _, b, c, d
6: d, c, b, a
```

to

```
1: a, b, c, d
4: d, c, b, a
6: d, c, b, a
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$arr = array(... your multi dimension array here ...);
foreach($arr as $idx => $row) {
    if (preg_grep('/^$/', $row)) {
        unset($arr[$idx]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
$source = array(
    array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
    array('d', '_', 'b', 'a'),
    array('a', 'b', '_', '_'),
    array('d', 'c', 'b', 'a'),
    array('_', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
    array('d', 'c', 'b', 'a'),
);

$sourceCount = count($source);

for($i=0; $i<$sourceCount; $i++)
{
  if(in_array("_", $source[$i])) unset($source[$i]);
}
```

See: http://ideone.com/Vfd6Z

Comment: The one issue I have with this solution is the assumption that $source is an ordered, consistent array.  For this example it works, but it is possible that the array has arbitrary keys, or else that is has previously been manipulated and has a key structure like {0,1,4,8}. To fix this you could use array_values() on $source both before and after the array manipulation.  Using a foreach instead of a for loop would work around both these issues.

Comment: You're right. This code will also work with any type of key: ideone.com/smNR9

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the multidimensional array and check to see if the array at position `i` contains any empty elements. If it does, call `unset($arr[i])` to remove it.

```
for($i=0,$size=sizeof($arr); $i < $size; $i++) {
    if( in_array( "", $arr[$i] ) )
        unset( $arr[$i] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate through a foreach loop myself something like:

```
<?php
    // Let's call our multidimensional array $md_array for this

    foreach ($md_array as $key => $array)
    {
        $empty_flag = false;

        foreach ($array as $key => $val)
        {
            if ($val == '')
            {
                $empty_flag = true;
            }
        }

        if ($empty_flag == true)
        {
            unset($md_array[$key]);
        }
    }
?>
```

There's almost definitely a more efficient way of doing this so anyone else who has a better solution feel free to let me and Alex know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Note: $arr is your array.

```
foreach ( $arr as $key => $line ) {

    foreach ( $line as $item ) {

        if ( empty( $item ) ) {

            unset( $arr[$key] );
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Cheers

Comment: this works, but its a poor approach, as you are ripping out the item while you are iterating over it.  it would be better to move the unset to the outer foreach, or else throw a break after the unset.

Comment: Thanks, didn't really think it through. fixed it now.