# Filter Empty/Null value from associative array in php (multidimensional array)

Tags: php

I want to remove null rows from assoctivate array, i.e. whose values are empty

[Already Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944459/remove-lines-with-empty-values-from-multidimensional-array-in-php)

```
 array[0]
      a =>  '101'
      b =>  '105'
      c =>  '103'

 array[1]
      a =>  ''
      b =>  ''
      c =>  ''

 array[2]
      a =>  '101'
      b =>  '105'
      c =>  '103'

 Desired result :- 

  array[0]
      a =>  '101'
      b =>  '105'
      c =>  '103'  

 array[1]
      a =>  '101'
      b =>  '105'
      c =>  '103'
```

Note :- This is a Subarray of array.i.e. Multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As went  through many post, I found simplest answer

```
//foreach

if (strlen(implode('', array_values($array_row))) > 0) {


}
```

This will not let empty row

Answer (score 1):

You can filter using `implode`.

```
$non_empty_rows = array_filter($array, 'implode');
```

That will collapse multiple null values or empty strings in each sub-array into a  single empty string which will evaluate as false.

[Runnable example at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6fDjn)